# Any way to create the custom option for all simple products in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I want to create a custom option for all simple product is there Any way to create the custom option for all simple products in Magento 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto magento admin and edit any product. Then goto custom options tab and add custom options according to your requirement.

Follow the youtube video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T5_o44hOA0c

Comment: thanks for the reply. I want to have custom option applied to all products.

Comment: Do you want to add same custom options for all products and need to apply at the same time? If yes then use the extension https://bsscommerce.com/magento-2-custom-option-template-extension.html